# Division of standard deviation of mean

Tags: error-analysis

I recorded the reading for $5$ oscillations of a pendulum 50 times. I got the reading as $4.47 \pm 0.02$ seconds , where $0.02$ s is the standard deviation of mean. To express this result for 1 oscillation, we should not divide the uncertainty (i.e. $0.02$) by $5$.

Why does this happen? And if instead of standard deviation of mean, it was standard deviation what should we do?

Comment: What are exactly the numbers? Seconds?

Comment: yes. Edited the answer.

Comment: [*Standard deviation of the mean*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Standard_deviation_of_the_mean) means the mean over many measurements with identical errors (i.i.d.), whereas here is a single measurement with a single error (even though you measure 5 oscillatiosn at once).

Comment: Re your edit (v4): does this mean your distribution of measurements had standard deviation $0.02\rm\,s \times\sqrt{50} \approx 0.14\,s$? That’s a pretty typical thumb-on-stopwatch timing precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised answer.  Sorry I misread your question earlier.

You wish to estimate the mean and standard deviation of the mean for the time of an oscillation.  You chose to take a random sample of 5 oscillation times, and you have 50 random samples, each of size 5.  From each sample of 5 you should evaluate the oscillation time, not the time for 5 oscillations.  That is, you are evaluating the time for an oscillation based on a sample of 5 times; not the sum of the times from the sample of size 5.  Then you use standard relationships, based on the samples, to evaluate the mean and standard deviation of the mean for a single oscillation time.  So what you have for the oscillation time, are estimates of the mean and standard deviation of the mean based on your 50 sets of 5 random samples.  That is, you already have the results for an oscillation based on your data.  Note: you are reporting the standard deviation for the mean of 50 samples, not the standard deviation of the entire sampling data.  Using the entire set of a data you can evaluate the standard deviation for the time of an oscillation for the total sample.  I think this is what @Roger Vadim was getting at in his earlier comment.

If you just recorded the data for the sum of 5 times for each sample, you can do the following.  Let Y represent the random variable for the sum of 5 oscillations and X the random variable for 1 oscillation.  That is, y(x) = 5 x for specific values x and y. You can show that the sample standard deviation of Y (and the standard deviation of the mean for Y) equals 5 times the sample standard deviation for X (and the standard deviation of the mean for X).  See for example the text Data Analysis for Scientists and Engoneers by Meyer.

Note: you are evaluating sample standard deviations as an estimate of the population standard deviation, and need to use the correct formula for the sample standard deviation; see any basic probability/statistics test.

Comment: You didn't misread. Your answer [v2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/673755/2) was in response to the question's [v3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/673538/3). Thanks for updating!

Answer (score 0):

The standard deviation is only defined for multiple measurements.

If we have only done 1 measurement, we cannot define a standard deviation for this single measurement. Using the formula will give us standard deviaion = 0.

So we have to use our multiple measurements (5 in this case) in order to find the error estimate via the standard deviation construct, then apply this result to the single measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out the issues with attempting to compute standard deviation or standard error in a single sample - you cannot measure variability with only one sample. I'll approach the more general case of taking a subset of the data, where N>1.

You found a mean of 4.47 and a standard error of 0.02 using 5 samples. If you wanted the standard error from 2 samples, you should not divide 0.02 by 2.5 - that would imply that you somehow got a *more precise* estimate of the mean from *less data*, which doesn't make any sense. Standard error of the mean decreases with sample size, not the reverse. The standard deviation of the sample, on the other hand, should remain roughly constant regardless of your sample size, since it is a function of the population itself and not of your sampling approach.

Comment: The standard deviation of the sample is not constant regardless of sample size; it changes as more data is gathered and as the number of measurements (size of sample) increases.  The (unknown) population standard deviation is constant; the sample standard deviation provides an estimate of the population standard deviation.

Comment: @JohnDarby I've clarified a bit - the standard deviation of a sample will vary somewhat depending on the sample, but it should not vary *significantly* regardless of the sample or sample size. My point is that sample standard deviation is not correlated with N, while standard error of the mean is.